# why is my function giving an error message

Tags: javascript

Hoping you good folk can help me with this one. I am trying to use a nav link to show a hidden div when clicked but I keep getting the error message 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement."

this appears for the line of code = if (contentOneClick.style.display == "none") yet if i taker either the word "style" or the word "display" out of this code then i do not get the error message which has left me confused as i have watched content of this being used and working well for others. below is the whole function code. The display is set to "none" in the style code. I am new to web development so my apologies if this is a silly question.

`document.getElementById('content-one').addEventListener("click", function() {

```
  var contentOneClick = document.getElementsByClassName(".content-one-container");

    if (contentOneClick.style.display == "none") 
    {
     console.log ("content is hidden");
    }
    else 
    {
      console.log("content is visible");
    }

});         `
```

Comment: That's because you are getting a `NodeList` in `contentOneClick` you're getting all elements with the class name `.content-one-container`.  If you dont want to use id and you're sure there's just one element with the classname try this:

```
if (contentOneClick[0].style.display == "none") 
```

Comment: Also, `getElementsByClassName` expects a *class name*, but you're giving it a *selector*. Remove the `.` if you want to use `getElementsByClassName`, or use `querySelectorAll` if you want to find all matches for a selector, or use `querySelector` if you just want to find the *first* match for a selector.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys. Yes i should have realised i was getting a NodeList with that. I have gone back and used an id rather than class name and taken the . away which has fixed the error message but the console log always tells me that the content is visible yet it is set to display:none in my style code and it is clearly not visible in the browser. Even when trying you solutions im still getting the same thing. I know the solution is a very simple one but im not seeing it and feeling very foolish right now

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getElementsByClassName` returns a `nodeList`, therefore, you should specify which element having class `content-one-container` you want to use:

```
var contentOneClick = document.getElementsByClassName("content-one-container")[0];
```

```
                                                       ^ remove the .
```

Comment: There's a [very well-established dupetarget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method) for this question. It's asked all the time. It doesn't need answering, just closing as a dupe and a comment to help the OP see how to apply the answers.

Comment: I know that this is a common question, but the code contains a syntax error as well which needs to be shown otherwise any attempt won't work

Comment: Well, technically not a syntax error. :-) (You *can* have a `.` in a class name, it's just an amazingly bad idea.) But likely a typo. There's a close reason for those, too. But whatever. :-)